# Webpack custom plugin to define a module

Tags: node.js, webpack, modernizr, webpack-2

I'm trying to write a small custom plugin for Webpack which will build a custom Modernizr object and expose it. I've found [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr-webpack-plugin) and [this loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-modernizr-loader), but loader seems hacky (it requires an empty file `.modernizrrc` even if I pass options directly), and plugin can only create a separate file.

I've borrowed some code from the aforementioned plugin, but cannot figure out the last step (how to expose `Modernizr` in the built file):

```
const modernizr = require('modernizr'),
  ConcatSource = require('webpack-sources/lib/ConcatSource'),
  CachedSource = require('webpack-sources/lib/CachedSource');

class BuildModernizrPlugin {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    let plugin = this;
    plugin._props = props;
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    let plugin = this;

    compiler.plugin('after-compile', (compiler, callback) => {
      modernizr.build(plugin._props, result => {
        plugin._modernizr = result;
        callback();
      });
    });

    compiler.plugin('emit', (compilation, callback) => {
      let source = new ConcatSource();
      source.add(plugin._modernizr);
      compilation.assets['modernizr.js'] = new CachedSource(source);
      callback();
    });
  }
}
```

#### webpack config

```
{
  //...
  plugins: [
    new BuildModernizrPlugin({
      options: [
        'setClasses'
      ],
      'feature-detects': [
        'es6/promises'
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

However it seems to create a separate `modernizr.js` file, whereas I want `Modernizr` code to be embedded into my output file. Any help is much appreciated.